# Can I Make a JQuery UI Layout Centered in a Column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I am new to JQuery UI and I have gotten the basic example working where the layout goes all the way to the edge of the page. What I'd like is this layout, but where the content is in a centered column, and you can see the background color on each side. So I added a div to the outside with some very simple CSS, like so:

```
.frame
{
   width:900px; 
   margin:0 auto;
}

<div class="frame">
    <div class="ui-layout-north">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-east">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-west">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-south">
</div>
```

Alas, instead of working like a normal div, I get a pop-up that says:

> UI Layout Initialization Error
>
> The center-pane element does not exist.
>
> The center-pane is a required element

Why does it do that, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance, and keep in mind, I may be making a very noobish error. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that you're still applying `layout()` to the document body:

```
$("body").layout({
    // options...
});
```

In that case, the layout engine won't find the pane elements since they don't reside in the body itself. A solution would be to apply `layout()` to your wrapper `<div>` element instead:

```
$("div.frame").layout({
    // options...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your end goal, you might want to try reversing this - put the div that will center your layout inside `#ui-layout-center` and give it `margin: 0 auto;`.